# Does the double damage inflicted "red skull" stat apply to all weapons?

Tags: dead-cells

I picked up a Fire Grenade with a red skull x2 stat that says "+100% damage inflicted on enemies. +100% damage taken!". Does the double damage inflicted apply to all my weapons? Or does it only apply to the item with the modifier?

[image: Fire Grenade with double damage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Dead Cells](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Affixes#Major_Affixes) wikia, **Double damage** entry states:

> Damage inflicted multiplier only affects the affixed item.